# Speeding up ./configure script restarts when it fails

Tags: performance, autotools

How to optimize restarting of ./configure script when it fails?

E.g. start ./configure to figure out missing dependency; start it again to figure out the next missing dependency and so on. If we have N missing dependencies, we have to wait for about N*(const+N/2) tests totally before we successfully configure it.

"./configure -C" fails, and "config.cache" is empty.

ccache is already in use. ./configure is executed by /bin/dash.

How to either

1. Force it to cache partial results?
2. Make it continue on failure and report all missing things at once?
3. Dramatically speed up re-running the same tests somehow.

Are there alternative ./configure script generators? May be I should hack something inside ./configure to enable caching or not exiting?

P.S. I wish ./configure just prints the list of Debian lib*-dev packages I need to install in order to satisfy it.

Comment: What package is so broken that config.cache isn't generated?

Comment: And what about systems that don't run Debian? Or what about when a package name changes? Or...

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, I mean it would be most comfortable for me.